# How to Place a script file at other machine root

Tags: 14.04

i want to place a script file on other machine root . here is my terminal command

```
scp /var/www/html/script.sh root@192.168.1.7:script.sh
```

it asks for root password. i enter correct root password but it says

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Do not use root. Use your admin account.

Answer (score 0):

By default openssh will denied any root login attempt. However, this can be allowed by modifying `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server side.

Make sure this line sets to yes and no commented out:

`PermitRootLogin yes`

And then reload your sshd.

However, above setup is not a good security practice. Instead use pubkey login.

the config line should be:

`PermitRootLogin without-password`.

1. On source machine genereate key, follow the wizard:
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. Above command will create `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and `.ssh/id_rsa` containing public and private key pair. 
   You need to copy `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content into the destination machine `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Make the directory and file if its not exist and make sure the ownership of the authorized_keys is `600`.
3. Now try scp attempt, it will asks for password that you have entered in step 1.

Comment: Correct but I would like to remark this is not good practice. Using root and using a root password is asking for problems

Comment: Yeah, edited with another `without-password` how to.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have have password-less sudo access, the following should work:

```
$ echo "My test file" > test 
$ scp test sudo_user@example.com:/tmp/
test
$ ssh sudo_user@example.com "sudo mv /tmp/test /"
$ ssh sudo_user@example.com "cat /test"
My test file
```

1. Create a test file.
2. Copy file to temp directory.
3. Move file to root directory.
4. Test that file is on the root directory.